# How to return the last string in a list that ends with digit in a list of list of list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a list of list of list of strings. Like this:

```
[[['F0','K4','N']], [['S', 'B2', 'A5']]]
```

I would like to return a list of string which contains the last item in each sublist which ends with a digit. So this should give me a result of:

```
['K4','A5']
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
result = []
    for line in poem_pronunciation:
        for words in line:
            for i,unit in reversed(list(enumerate(words))):
                if unit[-1] in '0123456789':
                    result.append(words[i])
    return result
```

This would give me a result of

```
['K4', 'F0', 'A5', 'B2']
```

Apparently it includes all strings which end with digit and in a reversed order. How to fix this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When adding an element, you may stop the loop with a `break`

```
def getLasts(poem_pronunciation):
    result = []
    for line in poem_pronunciation:
        for words in line:
            for i, unit in reversed(list(enumerate(words))):
                if unit[-1] in '0123456789':
                    result.append(words[i])
                    break
    return result
```

---

If you want to simplify the third look, see it another way

- collect the items that ends with a digts
- by reading in reversed way, and take the first, by using `next()` to get the first item of the iterator

  ```
  for line in poem_pronunciation:
      for words in line:
          result.append(next(x for x in words[::-1] if x[-1].isdigit()))
  ```

The simplification of all is just a matter of list comprehensions

```
def getLasts(poem_pronunciation):
    return [next(x for x in words[::-1] if x[-1].isdigit())
            for line in poem_pronunciation
            for words in line]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't learn how to use break in my class so I didn't know how to use it. Your answer is really helpful to me! I would simplify my code:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following nested comprehension:

```
l = [[['F0','K4','N']], [['S', 'B2', 'A5']]]

[next(x for x in s2[::-1] if x[-1].isdigit()) for s1 in l for s2 in s1]
# ['K4', 'A5']
```

Comment: Why the answers are : do it another way and don't explain its problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When face with a problem is usually better to split it parts, and create abstractions for it. For this case in particular you have two parts:

1. Iterate over the data
2. For a given list of elements find the last one that has a digit as last character.

For *2* you can create a function, one possibility, is:

```
def last(lst):
    """Returns the las element in a list that the last character is a list"""
    return next((e for e in reversed(lst) if e[-1].isdigit()), '')
```

Check that it works:

```
print(last(['F0', 'K4', 'N']))
```

**Output**

```
K4
```

Now *1* is relatively simple, and can be done like this:

```
result = []
for lines in poem:
    for words in lines:
        result.append(last(words))
print(result)
```

As an alternative you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like the following:

```
poem = [[['F0', 'K4', 'N']], [['S', 'B2', 'A5']]]


def last(lst):
    """Returns the las element in a list that the last character is a list"""
    return next((e for e in reversed(lst) if e[-1].isdigit()), '')


result = [last(words) for lines in poem for words in lines]

print(result)
```

*Output*

```
['K4', 'A5']
```

The important is the following, when face with a problem try to split it in parts, create abstractions for those parts and put those parts together as a final step.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you use a function to do this task so you can refer to it at any time.

I have made two functions first `ends_with_digit()` which checks if a string ends with a number or not by using `int` function inside `try` statement.

```
def ends_with_digit(string):
    try:
        int(string[-1])
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

then, You need a function that returns the last items. Because you have 3d `list` you need three loops to accomplish the task. after you check the element you have to stop the loop if the statement is `True` so that the last loop does not continue to append all items.

```
def last_digit_items(list):
    out = []
    for sub1 in list:
        for sub2 in sub1:
            for sub3 in reversed(sub2):
                if ends_with_digit(sub3):
                    out.append(sub3)
                    break
    return out
```

another way could do this by filtering the list recursively and then index the last item of each sublist but the function above is much simpler for your case.

to test the function run the following print statement

```
print(last_digit_items([[['F0','K4','N']], [['S', 'B2', 'A5']]]))
```

and it returns:

```
['K4', 'A5']
```